# duplicate rows in my counting by group with data.table in R

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I'm really sorry to ask this dumb question but I don't get what is going wrong.
I have a dataset which I convert into a data.table object :

```
#generate 100,000 ids associated to a group in a data-set called base
id=c(1:100000)
group=sample(c(1:5),100000,TRUE)
base=cbind(id,group)
base=as.data.table(base)
```

I make a basic group by computation to get the number of rows by group, and the result table still contains the same number of rows

```
counting=base[,COUNT:= .N, by = group]
nrow(counting)
#100000
```

What did I miss? Is there an option in data.table in order to address my problem?

Comment: I wonder if you meant `counting=base[,list(COUNT= .N), by = group]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would have been crazy

Comment: pleasure to help you. :)

Comment: @akrun If you think it's worth doing it, I'm happy to do that. :)

Comment: @akrun Mission done. If any revision is necessary, please let me know. You are more than welcome to edit my answer.

Comment: Use `setDT(base)` to modify `base` in-place, with no need to reassign (`base = `). This works if you construct base as `base = data.frame(id,group)`, anyway. (`cbind` makes a matrix.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking akrun's comment, I decided to provide an answer. It seems that you were not sure how to summarise your data and got confused. First, one point about constructing a data set:

```
set.seed(123)
id    = c(1:100000)
group = sample(c(1:5),100000,TRUE)
base  = data.frame(id,group)
setDT(base)

base

        id group
 1:      1     2
 2:      2     4
 3:      3     3
 4:      4     5
 5:      5     5
 ....
```

When you use `cbind()` on multiple vectors, they are coerced to the same class to make a matrix. The safer way to go is to use `data.frame()`, which allows mixed column classes. And, if you have a data.frame, you can turn it into a data.table by reference with `setDT`, without needing to assign the result.

**Adding a new column.** Your code was basically adding a new column in the data.table object. When you use `:=`, you are doing the equivalent of `mutate()` in `dplyr` or `transform()` in base R, with one important difference. With `:=`, the column is added to the data.table by reference, so there is no need to assign the result.

```
base[, COUNT := .N, by = group]

base

   id group COUNT
1:  1     2 20099
2:  2     4 19934
3:  3     3 20001
4:  4     5 19933
5:  5     5 19933
...
```

Here, you are counting how many data points exist for each group, and you are assigning the values to all rows. For instance, the total count of group 2 is 20099. You give this number to all rows with `group == 2`. You are creating a new column, not summarizing the data. Hence, you still have 100000 rows. The number of rows in `base` is the same as ever. There is currently no function to modify the number of rows by reference.

**Summarising the data.** If you want to count how many data points exist for each group and summarize the data, you want the following.

```
dt2 <- base[, .(COUNT = .N), by = group]

dt2

   group COUNT
1:     2 20099
2:     4 19934
3:     3 20001
4:     5 19933
5:     1 20033

dim(dt2)

[1] 5 2
```

Here, you want to make sure that you use `=`, not `:=` since you are summarising the data. It is necessary to assign the result because we are creating a new data.table. I hope this clears up your mind.

Comment: Don't do `dt1 <- `. The newly-added column is already in `base` and assigning the whole thing serves no purpose. (I see that it helps you illustrate what's going on by calling `dim` after, but the OP should not be encouraged to do it.)

Comment: @Frank Thanks for your comment. I understand your comment. I had the intension to follow what the OP did (i.e., `counting=base[,COUNT:= .N, by = group]`). In addition, I had the intension to use dim() as well. Please feel free to edit my answer and help the OP. Once again, thanks for your comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed?

```
base$regroup = group
base[, .(Count = .N, regroup), by = group]
```

gives 100,000 rows even though group and regroup are identical?